# Is Windows Azure a multitenant operating system?

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I am trying to understand what is the difference between [Windows Azure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform) and other competitors, in the technical level.

From what I understand Azure is a multitenant OS, meaning, that every application is running in some kind of a sandbox based on [Hyper-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V).
In other words, every application being loaded is running by Azure in its closed sandbox.
Meaning, the operating system is "real", but the application is running in a virtual environment.

That is **opposed** to, lets say, [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud), where they give you a virtual machine, with a full virtual operating system (a virtual computer).

Am I right, or have I got it totally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to multi-tenancy and dedication of an instance to one tenant, both Azure and Amazon EC2 are exactly alike.  Both dedicate a VM to you as a compute instance.

Difference between EC2 and Azure (currently) is that Amazon provides you a real VM with an OS and an ability and a REQUIREMENT to manage the OS as well as anything installed on that OS.

Azure takes away some of the "ABILITY" power away from you (currently you don't get to manipulate the OS) while at the same time taking maintenance as well.

In my mind, unless you have some special requirements that require a full access to the OS (and upcoming Azure release will let you actually install stuff on your instances like legacy COM components, etc) I would stick with Azure as it has a less of an administrative cost.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Azure gives you VMs running Windows, just like Amazon EC2 does.

Answer (score 2):

No. **In Azure you get a VMs as well** (one per role instance). They are just more abstracted from you, than Amazon or Rackspace.

Answer (score 2):

You get different VMs in Azure as well. What happens in Amazon EC2 for instance is that the abstraction ends at the hardware level. Everything above the virtual machines, ie the operating system updates, the application frameworks, the web server, etc; everything needs to be managed by you.

With Azure, the abstraction is taken far above just the hardware level and to an entire application framework level. For instance Web roles are nothing but VMs, preloaded with IIS and .net framework (and other application frameworks) tuned to serve web traffic. You are able to just deploy your application and all the other configurations are handled for you, but underneath it, it is still a VM.